# How to get all VM's Operating System information from My Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How to get all VM's Operating System information from My Azure Subscription. Like operation System Name and Version.

Ex: - Windows 10.0.1380.

Comment: you'd need to create a script that would query the vms and return that data. there is no api to get this data at platform (azure) level. azure only knows base image and os type (windows\linux)

Comment: There is no direct way to do that, but you can achieve it through a script, no matter CLI or PowerShell.